# Excel Formula returning error:

Tags: excel

I am trying to add two cells in excel but it gives an `#Value!` because I believe I am adding the space if error. Is there a way to add without using a 0 for example because I need to copy the formula down and if there is no value, I want it to be  a blank not zero. Thanks!

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B4*J4),"",(B4*J4)),"")+IFERROR(IF(C4="","",VLOOKUP(C4,Sheet2!$R$1:$S$12,2,FALSE))*J4,"")
```

Comment: either wrap the whole formula in an IFERROR to catch the error from summing non numeric values, or resolve the error and then wrap it all in an IF to output space rather than zero.

Comment: How would you resolve the error? THanks

Comment: What would be the intended result if only 1 side of the equation is an error? For example if the VLOOKUP does not find the value C4 in the range it will return an error. Would you just want to return `B4*J4`?

Comment: Also I don't understand the use of ISBLANK. Even if one or both of the cells are blank it will multiply the values (which it will assume as 0) and then resolve if that returned value is blank. It won't be blank cause it will be equal to 0.

Comment: @John can you please post screenshots of the data? If you do, it will be much easier to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=IFERROR(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(B4*J4),"",(B4*J4)),"")+IFERROR(IF(C4="","",VLOOKUP(C4,Sheet2!$R$1:$S$12,2,FALSE))*J4,""),"")`

Comment: This is always returning a space even values are there. Thanks

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your data? That will help

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following solution:

```
=IF((B4*J4)+ IFERROR(IF(C4="",0,VLOOKUP(C4,Sheet2!$R$1:$S$12,2,FALSE)*J4),0)=0,"",(B4*J4)+ IFERROR(IF(C4="",0,VLOOKUP(C4,Sheet2!$R$1:$S$12,2,FALSE)*J4),0))
```

I removed the ISBLANK as per my comments above. Only left IFERROR on the VLOOKUP and wrapped everything in an IF to catch in the event that formula returns zero. Regards,